# How to feed multiple inputs to tf.keras.Model.predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, predict

Given this simple tensorflow toy model

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = {
    "a":tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name="input_a"),
    "b":tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name="input_b")
}
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Add()([inputs["a"], inputs["b"]])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

I can get its output by invoking it with inputs as defined, so the following:

```
model({"a":2,"b":3})
```

Gives the output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=5.0>
```

But invoking the predict function:

```
model.predict({"a":2,"b":3})
```

Gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'int'>"} values), <class 'NoneType'>
```

So how do I correctly invoke the predict function when my model has more than a single input as in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `predict` method can handle a dictionary of BATCHES of numpy arrays, this works:
`model.predict({'a': np.full((1,), 3), 'b': np.full((1,), 2)})`
and outputs `<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([5.], dtype=float32)>`
In this case, the batch size is equal to 1.