# Keras Sequence Named input with Batch format

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sequence

In a Keras Sequence for a model that has named inputs what is the format that the sequence needs to return assuming it has batches as well?

```py
{
    'feature_1': [ batch_size, time ],
    'feature_2': [ batch_size, time ],
}
```

Or

```
[{
    #Batch item 1
    'feature_1' : [ time ]
    'feature_2' : [ time ]
},
{
    #Batch item 2
    'feature_1' : [ time ]
    'feature_2' : [ time ]
}]
```

Given a model like this:

```
        model = Model(
            inputs = [ feature_1, feature_2 ],
            outputs = outputs
        )
```

And `Input` having the correct name:

```
feature_1 = Input(name = 'feature_1', batch_size = 16, shape = (1000,)
feature_2 = Input(name = 'feature_2', batch_size = 16, shape = (1000,)
```

Currently I keep getting

```
ValueError: Layer "model_1" expects 1 input(s), but it received 16 input tensors. 

Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, ... ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to feed multiple inputs to tf.keras.Model.predict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428068/how-to-feed-multiple-inputs-to-tf-keras-model-predict)

Comment: TLDR: the second option, but values in the dictionary have to be numpy arrays instead of lists